# Right Column not perfectly aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a lms for a project,

But the problem is the Calendar is not properly horizonatly aligned. It's kind of aligned middle of the screen. I want it to push right corner but it is not happening at the moment.

I'm using Bootstrap.

Here's [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVepYb) link

```js
$(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
    
    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });
});
```

```css
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}

body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 
 
}

.nav-sidebar { 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0; 
   /* border: 1px solid #ddd; */
}
.nav-sidebar a {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    transition: all 0.08s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
}
.nav-sidebar .active a { 
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #428bca; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666; 
}
.nav-sidebar .active a:hover {
    background-color: #428bca;   
}
.nav-sidebar .text-overflow a,
.nav-sidebar .text-overflow .media-body {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

/* Right-aligned sidebar */
.nav-sidebar.pull-right { 
    border-right: 0; 
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd; 
}
.nav-sidebar.pull-right a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; 
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; 
}

.center_row{
 
  max-width: 800px;
     margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left:25px;
    margin-right: 150px;
  color:#428bca;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.left-side{
 float:right; 
}

.navbar > .container {width:auto;}






* {box-sizing:border-box;}
ul {list-style-type: none;}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}

.month {
    padding: 70px 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #428bca;
}

.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.weekdays {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.days {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777;
}

.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #428bca;
    color: white !important
}

/* Add media queries for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 13.1%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.5%;}
    .days li .active {padding: 2px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
    .weekdays li, .days li {width: 12.2%;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="index.js"></script> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="  http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
</head>


<body>
<!---FIXED NAV BAR START --->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation" container="false">
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsable">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
  <img src="aaa.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="70" height="35">
</a>
</div><div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapsable">  
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<p class="navbar-text">Logged in as Some Person</p>
<li>
  <a href="/log_out">
    Log out
  </a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<!---FIXED NAV BAR END --->


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="center_row">
<div class="row ">
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="right_side">
<h3>LEARNING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM OF AAA</h3>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="left_side" style="margin-left:100px;margin-right:-500px;">
<h3 id="demo" class="text-right" style="text-transform: uppercase; "></h3>
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
</script>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>


<br>

<!-----LEFT HAND NAV BAR-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

<div class="container">
 
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <nav class="nav-sidebar">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> AAA Research Publications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;">AAA Quaterly News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;">Student Handbooks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;">Award Handbooks</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">Regulations</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">Examination Time Tables</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">Class Time Tables</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
  
        <div class="col-md-8" >
          <h3 style="color: #428bca;">LATEST NEWS</h3>
        </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-md-2" id="pull-right" style="float:right !important;">
  





<div class="month">      
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">❮</li>
    <li class="next">❯</li>
    <li style="text-align:center">
      August<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>Mo</li>
  <li>Tu</li>
  <li>We</li>
  <li>Th</li>
  <li>Fr</li>
  <li>Sa</li>
  <li>Su</li>
</ul>

<ul class="days">  
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
</ul>




  </div>
  
  
  
    </div>
</div>



</div>
</div>

<!-----LEFT HAND NAV BAR END-->





</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
What i want is as follows,

[image]

Comment: why you are using col-md-4..try to use col-sm-12 and you will get container in mid..

Comment: you are looking for this http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/JXVMLd

Comment: columns are center align.. and they are in middle of screen too.. Can you please show in diagram so i can make like that?

Comment: @Leothelion i edited the question, above image is what i want

Comment: like this one http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/VaNyGm

Comment: check this one too http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/BKEJOY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my view you should change the column grid as  you are using `col-md-4` but as you said you need it then go with col-md-12 and `container-fluid` to get the desired result.

container always have fixed width in different different resolution(in px) but if you want full width then try to use `container-fluid` which will take 100% according to all screen.

Check my [codepan](http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/BKEJOY). I have removed row as it was taking extra margin and i have applied container-fluid to get the desired output. hope it will help.

**NOTE**  In `.navbar-brand` class you are using fix height(50px) by which your logo image is going out. Either increase the size of nav bar or remove that height so logo will be in nav bar. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much... this is what i want :)

Comment: M glad that i could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your  section with below

```
<!-----LEFT HAND NAV BAR-->
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav class="nav-sidebar">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> AAA Research Publications</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">AAA Quaterly News</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Student Handbooks</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Award Handbooks</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Regulations</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Examination Time Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Class Time Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="nav-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3 style="color: #428bca;">LATEST NEWS</h3>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4" id="pull-right" style="float:right !important;">


        <div class="month">
          <ul>
            <li class="prev">❮</li>
            <li class="next">❯</li>
            <li style="text-align:center">
              August<br>
              <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <ul class="weekdays">
          <li>Mo</li>
          <li>Tu</li>
          <li>We</li>
          <li>Th</li>
          <li>Fr</li>
          <li>Sa</li>
          <li>Su</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="days">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>7</li>
          <li>8</li>
          <li>9</li>
          <li><span class="active">10</span></li>
          <li>11</li>
          <li>12</li>
          <li>13</li>
          <li>14</li>
          <li>15</li>
          <li>16</li>
          <li>17</li>
          <li>18</li>
          <li>19</li>
          <li>20</li>
          <li>21</li>
          <li>22</li>
          <li>23</li>
          <li>24</li>
          <li>25</li>
          <li>26</li>
          <li>27</li>
          <li>28</li>
          <li>29</li>
          <li>30</li>
          <li>31</li>
        </ul>


      </div>


  </div>


 </div>
</div>

<!-----LEFT HAND NAV BAR END-->
```

Let me know if it doesn't look exactly like you want.

Comment: Whenever giving answer with code,  you should mention what you did so op can get idea and he don't have to read full code. Thank you